# Passagem de valor fixo no $this->input->post no PHP

Tags: php

boa noite
Eu tenho o método abaixo que adiciona valores preenchidos de um modal

```
public function ajax_add()
{

    $this->_validate();
    $data = array(
            'owner' => $this->input->post('owner'),
            'dpo' => $this->input->post('dpo'),
            'grupo' => $this->input->post('grupo'),
            'sub_grupo' => $this->input->post('sub_grupo'),
            'semana' => $this->input->post('semana'),
            'cod_id' => $this->input->post('cod_id'),
            'atividade' => $this->input->post('atividade'),
            'obj_esperado' => $this->input->post('obj_esperado'),
            'alcancado' => $this->input->post('alcancado'),
            'conc_esti' => $this->input->post('conc_esti'),
            'anl_envolvidos' => $this->input->post('anl_envolvidos'),

    );
    $insert = $this->projeto->save($data);
    echo json_encode(array("status" => TRUE));
```

Porém, eu preciso passar mais dois valores fixos nesta adição que serão:

```
    'operacao' => $this->input->post("INS"),
    'data_reg' => $this->input->post(NOW()),
```

Isso servirá para incluir qual operação esta sendo feita e a data. Estes valores não virão do FORM MODAL, terão que ser fixos.

O meu ajax de adição ou update, esta assim:

```
function save()
{
$('#btnSave').text('salvando...'); //change button text
$('#btnSave').attr('disabled',true); //set button disable 
var url;
  if(save_method == 'add') {
    url = "<?php echo site_url('projeto/ajax_add')?>";
} else {
    url = "<?php echo site_url('projeto/ajax_update')?>";
}

// ajax adding data to database
$.ajax({
    url : url,
    type: "POST",
    data: $('#form').serialize(),
    dataType: "JSON",
    success: function(data)
    {

        if(data.status) //if success close modal and reload ajax table
        {
            $('#modal_form').modal('hide');
            reload_table();
        }
        else
        {
            for (var i = 0; i < data.inputerror.length; i++) 
            {

   $('[name="'+data.inputerror[i]+'"]').parent().parent().addClass('has- 
   error'); //select parent twice to select div form-group class and add 
   has-error class

   $('[name="'+data.inputerror[i]+'"]').next().text(data.error_string[i]); 
   //select span help-block class set text error string
            }
        }
        $('#btnSave').text('save'); //change button text
        $('#btnSave').attr('disabled',false); //set button enable 


    },
    error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)
    {
        alert('Erro adicionando ou atualizando registro');
        $('#btnSave').text('save'); //change button text
        $('#btnSave').attr('disabled',false); //set button enable 

    }
   });
}
```

Como eu poderia fazer isso ? fiz alguns testes mas sem sucesso.

Muito Obrigado.

Comment: E porque você não insere direto no código esses dois valores fixos?

Comment: Mas em que local Andrei? no próprio ajax ?

Comment: Bom, resolvi o problema: foi só passar assim:  'operacao' => ("INS"),
    'data_reg' => $dataReg, no codigo PHP e funcionou. simples.